# Is it a good idea to create a 'middleware backend' between customer backend and my frontend?

Tags: php, performance, frameworks, proxy, backend

The thing is this, I have several projects where the customer have an horrific backend definition, returning data in several formats and with lot of stuff I don't need. Since Im doing the mobile webapps, Im creating a middle layer in php, using slimframework (www.slimframework.com), which basically give me a RESTFUL syntax also removing all the data I dont need, and in the format I want (JSON). Of course this middle layer will be deployed in customer backend, so even if makes me so easy the frontend implementation, im a little worry about the performance and also adding another break-point to the 'chain'. For performance, every call I get to my slimframework Im saving in a unique JSON data as a cache, and I have a text file where I can configure easily the max amount of seconds of each petition.

More technically, Im reading with curl the real web service, convert to PHP object, remove and change all the data I need and then make a json_encode...also, Ive though another ideas, like creating a batch process in cron that pulls all the web services from customer and generate local jsons... dont worry about not getting the lastest data, since is an video catch up application, so Im caching every WS but the final url is no cached.

Is there any simpler solution for my workflow?

Comment: A famous aphorism of David Wheeler goes: All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection;[2] this is often deliberately mis-quoted with "abstraction" substituted for "indirection". Kevlin Henney's corollary to this is, "...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection."

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good to me.

Sure, you're adding a new potential point of failure, but you're also adding a new place at which problems can be caught and handled resiliently — it sounds like the existing back-end cannot be trusted to do that itself. Unit/stress test the heck out of your intercept layer and gain all confidence that you're not adding *undue* new risk.

As for performance? Well, as with anything, you need to benchmark it and then balance the results with the other benefits. I love a good abstraction layer<sup>†</sup> and as long as you're not seeing service-denying levels of performance drop (and I don't see why you should) it's almost certainly well worth it.

If nothing else you're abstracting away this data backend that you appear to have no control over, which will effectively allow you complete flexbility to switch it out for something else someday.

And if the backend changes spontaneously? Well, at least you only need to adjust some isolated portion of your intercept layer, and not every piece of your customer-facing front-end that relies on pieces of that third-party data.

In conclusion, it seems to me like a perfectly robust solution and I think you should absolutely go ahead with it.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> of course, you don't want *too many* of them. It's up to us to decide how many is appropriate. I usually find *zero* to be an unacceptable answer. :)</sup>